# i m using tts to read string arrays item one by one using for loop. but it always speal last item. how to set tts to speak one string after another

Tags: android, text-to-speech

my global variables

```
String[] arr;
int cIndex=0; 
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;
```

this is in on creat i set onclick listener on button btnSpeak and used
for loop in it. i am trying to call speak method till the length of arr[] but it speaks only the last index.

but when i dont use loop and clik button so it speaks words one by one but i have to click button for every words in string.

i want it to speak all the element of string array arr[] on just one click.
please hepl

```
btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String text = txtText.getText().toString();
            String[] arr = text.split(" ");
            int mLen = arr.length;

           for (int i=0;i<=mLen;i++)
            speakOut();



         }

    });
```

this is my speakOut method

```
    private void speakOut() {


    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    String[] arr = text.split(" ");

    int mLen = arr.length;


    try {
        if (cIndex <= mLen) {
            String arr_s = arr[cIndex];
            tts.speak(arr_s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            cIndex = cIndex + 1;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(Div_string.this, "Nothig to speak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced same issue. hope my answer will help someone.

I have used arraylist of data with few interval gap in kotlin.

```
 private fun convertTextToSpeech() {
    val speech = arrayList.joinToString(separator = "?")
    val myHash = HashMap<String, String>()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"done")
    myHash[TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID] = "done"

    val splitSpeech = speech.split("\\?".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()

    for (i in splitSpeech.indices) {
        Log.i("responseString",splitSpeech[i])
        if (i == 0) { // Use for the first splited text to flush on audio stream
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' },TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, null);
            } else {
                tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash);
            }

        } else { // add the new test on previous then play the TTS
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, null);
            } else {
                tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, myHash);
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts?.playSilentUtterance(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
        } else {
            tts?.playSilence(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
        }
    }
}
```